# PyPDF2 Splitting a single PDF into multiple PDFs with variable lengths

Tags: python, csv, pypdf

Hello I have a PDF file with 142 Pages. I want to Split this file into multiple PDF Files. I got an CSV with the startPage and endPage of the Single files. I thought of something like **writer.addpage(startPage[i]:endPage[i])**

Is this possible ?

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post all your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I found a work-a-round:

```
for k in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
pages=list(range(int(startPage[counter]) , int(endPage[counter])))
pages.append(int(endPage[counter]))
pdfWriter= PdfFileWriter();
for page_num in pages:
    pdfWriter.addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num))
output_filename= datum[counter]+"_Freigabe IT-Lösung "+bezeichnung[counter]+".pdf"
with open(output_filename, 'wb') as out:
    pdfWriter.write(out)
counter += 1
```

Comment: You could do `pages=list(range(int(startPage[counter]) , int(endPage[counter]) + 1))` and avoid doing the extra `append` call for the last page

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can use "pdf.pages[key]". Instead of key, you can also use a slice and iterate over it